# Where should I find the jenkins hook URL for github for jenkins plus github setup

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to find out the way in which I want to start building the jenkin job on one of my Github repository commits. When i was going through the documentation for the same I came to know i have to add jenkins url on github settings but unfortunately I am not able to find out which of my jenkins URL i should put there?

Comment: I believe it depends on the plug-in you are using; some do it for you. Which are you using?